# How do I create child XElement based on values in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xml:lang="de">
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/9783748258957.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Inhalt">
<p class="toc-ch"><span class="bi">4 Main Value</span></p>
<p class="toc-h1">4.1 Child Value 1</p>
<p class="toc-h1">4.2 Child Value 2</p>
<p class="toc-h1">4.3 Child Value 3</p>
<p class="toc-h2">4.3.1 Grand-child Value</p>
<p class="toc-h2">4.3.2 Grand-child Value</p>
<p class="toc-h2">4.3.3 Grand-child Value</p>
<p class="toc-h2">4.3.4 Grand-child Value</p>
<p class="toc-h1">4.4 Child Value 4</p>
<p class="toc-h2">4.4.1 Grand-child Value</p>
<p class="toc-h2">4.4.2 Grand-child Value</p>
<p class="toc-h2">4.4.3 Grand-child Value</p>
<p class="toc-h2">4.4.4 Grand-child Value</p>
<p class="toc-h1">4.5 Child Value 5</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the XML in the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1" xml:lang="de">
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/9783748258957.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<navMap>
<navPoint id="navPoint-01" playOrder="01"><navLabel><text>4 Main Value</text></navLabel>
    <navPoint id="navPoint-02" playOrder="02"><navLabel><text>4.1 Child Value 1</text></navLabel></navPoint>
    <navPoint id="navPoint-03" playOrder="03"><navLabel><text>4.2 Child Value 2</text></navLabel></navPoint>
    <navPoint id="navPoint-04" playOrder="04"><navLabel><text>4.3 Child Value 3</text></navLabel>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-05" playOrder="05"><navLabel><text>4.3.1 Grand-child Value</text></navLabel></navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-06" playOrder="06"><navLabel><text>4.3.2 Grand-child Value</text></navLabel></navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-07" playOrder="07"><navLabel><text>4.3.3 Grand-child Value</text></navLabel></navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-08" playOrder="08"><navLabel><text>4.3.4 Grand-child Value</text></navLabel></navPoint></navPoint>
    <navPoint id="navPoint-09" playOrder="09"><navLabel><text>4.4 Child Value 4</text></navLabel>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-10" playOrder="10"><navLabel><text>4.4.1 Grand-child Value</text></navLabel></navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-11" playOrder="11"><navLabel><text>4.4.2 Grand-child Value</text></navLabel></navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-12" playOrder="12"><navLabel><text>4.4.3 Grand-child Value</text></navLabel></navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-13" playOrder="13"><navLabel><text>4.4.4 Grand-child Value</text></navLabel></navPoint></navPoint>
    <navPoint id="navPoint-14" playOrder="14"><navLabel><text>4.5 Child Value 5</text></navLabel></navPoint></navPoint>
</navMap>
</body>
</ncx>
```

How do I achieve this using `foreach` loop?

I want to nest the elements based on the `class` attribute. So, `toc-ch` is the main element, `toc-h1` goes under `toc-ch` and `toc-h2` goes under `toc-h1`

I am unable to make it nested. Now this is only one `<div id="inhalt">` and I have multiple `<div>` elements. The structure remains the same for each of the classes.

This is what I have done:

```
XDocument xtocdoc = XDocument.Load("epubv3TOC.xml");
XNamespace xtocNamespace = xtocdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
int navPointValue = 1;
int playOrdervalue = 1;

foreach (var value in breakslist)
{
    var valueElements = value.Descendants(htmlNamespace + "p").ToList();
    foreach (var values in valueElements)
        if (values.Attribute("class") != null)
        {
            if (values.Attribute("class") != null && values.Attribute("class").Value.Contains("ch"))
            {
                xtocdoc.Descendants(xtocNamespace + "navMap").FirstOrDefault(de => de != null)
                       .Add(new XElement(xtocNamespace + "navPoint", new XAttribute("id", "navPoint-" + navPointValue)
                                                            , new XAttribute("playOrder", playOrdervalue)
                                                            , new XElement(xtocNamespace + "navLabel"
                                                            , new XElement(xtocNamespace + "text", "ch"))));
                continue;
            }
            else if (values.Attribute("class") != null && values.Attribute("class").Value.Contains("h1"))
            {
                xtocdoc.Descendants(xtocNamespace + "navMap").FirstOrDefault(de => de != null)
                                                        .Elements(xtocNamespace + "navPoint")
                                                        .FirstOrDefault(el => el != null)
                                                        .Add(new XElement(xtocNamespace + "navPoint", new XAttribute("id", "navPoint-" + navPointValue)
                                                            , new XAttribute("playOrder", playOrdervalue)
                                                            , new XElement(xtocNamespace + "navLabel"
                                                            , new XElement(xtocNamespace + "text", "h1"))));
                continue;
            }
            else if (values.Attribute("class") != null && values.Attribute("class").Value.Contains("h2"))
            {
                xtocdoc.Descendants(xtocNamespace + "navMap").FirstOrDefault(de => de != null)
                                                        .Elements(xtocNamespace + "navPoint")
                                                        .FirstOrDefault(el => el != null)
                                                        .Add(new XElement(xtocNamespace + "navPoint", new XAttribute("id", "navPoint-" + navPointValue)
                                                            , new XAttribute("playOrder", playOrdervalue)
                                                            , new XElement(xtocNamespace + "navLabel"
                                                            , new XElement(xtocNamespace + "text", "h2"))));
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, that's your current input, yes? Could you include your desired output in the question? And is the intention to use the "4.3.1" (etc) part of each text value to determine the nesting? What about the trailing "3.1" (etc) part at end of each input element?

Comment: Yes, that is my current input and I have updated the question with my desired output. Ignore the `playOrder` and the `id` attributes. But if you look at the output, the elements are nested. Basically it is like, all the `toc-h1` go under `toc-ch` and all `toc-h2` go under `toc-h1`.

Comment: The fact that grand-child values aren't treated the same way as other elements (there's a suffix added in the output, which isn't present for other elements) makes this trickier. Please could you check that's *exactly* the input and output you're expecting?

Comment: So you want to do the nesting based on the `class` attribute, not on the text values? It would really help if you'd specify everything within the question, rather than just in comments.

Comment: Okay, I'll look when I get a chance, but it may well not be until tomorrow (UK time). (If you could show what you've already tried, that would improve the question too.) Hopefully someone else will be able to provide an answer in a shorter time.

Comment: Your output values still have a suffix - for example, the input value of "4.3.4 Grand-child Value" results in "4.3.4 Grand-child Value 3.4" - is that part of the requirement, or are you *only* interested in the nesting?

Comment: Finally - if you indented your output XML, the nesting would be a lot clearer.

Comment: The output does not meet the schema in the document.  Also the nesting isn't very clear.  I recommend you look at xml in a view.  You can view xml in VS using menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File : Paste xml into view.  Warnings and Errors will be displayed in the Error List like any compiler error.

Comment: @jdweng -  I have updated the out XML in the question. It was a mistake from my end. Now, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution using Xml Linq.. Why is there two nested levels of navPoint? :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication110
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XElement body = root.Element(ns + "body");

            string newBodyStr = "<body><navMap></navMap></body>";
            XElement newBodyX = XElement.Parse(newBodyStr);

            XElement navMap = newBodyX.Element("navMap");

            int count = 1;


            foreach (XElement p in body.Descendants(ns + "p"))
            {
                string innerText = (string)p;

                XElement newNavPoint = new XElement("navPoint", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("id", "navPoint-" + count.ToString("d2")),
                    new XAttribute("playOrder", count.ToString("d2")),
                    new XElement("navLabel", new XElement("text", innerText))
                });
                navMap.Add(newNavPoint);
                count++;

            }

            body.ReplaceWith(newBodyX);
            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle the nesting, you need to keep track of your current top-level `navPoint`, and your current child `navPoint` (if any). You can then decide where to add a new element based on the `class` of the `p` element.

Here's some sample code to do that. It doesn't do anything with the title etc - I've focused on the nesting:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XNamespace ncx = "http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/";
        XNamespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
        // Skipped creating all the rest of the structure: focusing on the
        // navMap
        var navMap = new XElement(ncx + "navMap");
        var inhalt = input.Descendants(xhtml + "div")
            .Single(div => (string) div.Attribute("id") == "Inhalt");

        XElement currentTop = null;
        XElement currentChild = null;

        int index = 1;
        foreach (var element in inhalt.Elements())
        {
            string id = $"navPoint-{index++:00}";
            var point = new XElement(ncx + "navPoint", new XAttribute("id", id));
            var navLabel = new XElement(ncx + "navLabel", element.Value);
            point.Add(navLabel);
            // TODO: playOrder attribute, text element etc. They're not important for nesting.
            switch (element.Attribute("class")?.Value)
            {
                case "toc-ch":
                    currentTop = point;
                    currentChild = null;
                    navMap.Add(point);
                    break;
                case "toc-h1":
                    if (currentTop == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("toc-h1 with no toc-ch");
                    }
                    currentChild = point;
                    currentTop.Add(point);
                    break;
                case "toc-h2":
                    if (currentChild == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("toc-h2 with no toc-h1");
                    }
                    currentChild.Add(point);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown class attribute");
            }
        }

        var output = new XDocument(new XElement(ncx + "ncx", navMap));
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, settings))
        {
            output.Save(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/">
  <navMap>
    <navPoint id="navPoint-01">
      <navLabel>4 Main Value</navLabel>
      <navPoint id="navPoint-02">
        <navLabel>4.1 Child Value 1</navLabel>
      </navPoint>
      <navPoint id="navPoint-03">
        <navLabel>4.2 Child Value 2</navLabel>
      </navPoint>
      <navPoint id="navPoint-04">
        <navLabel>4.3 Child Value 3</navLabel>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-05">
          <navLabel>4.3.1 Grand-child Value</navLabel>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-06">
          <navLabel>4.3.2 Grand-child Value</navLabel>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-07">
          <navLabel>4.3.3 Grand-child Value</navLabel>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-08">
          <navLabel>4.3.4 Grand-child Value</navLabel>
        </navPoint>
      </navPoint>
      <navPoint id="navPoint-09">
        <navLabel>4.4 Child Value 4</navLabel>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-10">
          <navLabel>4.4.1 Grand-child Value</navLabel>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-11">
          <navLabel>4.4.2 Grand-child Value</navLabel>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-12">
          <navLabel>4.4.3 Grand-child Value</navLabel>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navPoint-13">
          <navLabel>4.4.4 Grand-child Value</navLabel>
        </navPoint>
      </navPoint>
      <navPoint id="navPoint-14">
        <navLabel>4.5 Child Value 5</navLabel>
      </navPoint>
    </navPoint>
  </navMap>
</ncx>
```