# How do I replace values from the main XML file and save it as a new file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have a XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/9780737770551.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<brea name="Chapter01">
<p class="ch-title"><a id="page_15"></a><small>Some Text</small></p>
<p class="h1">Some Text</p>
<p class="h2">Some Text</p>
<p class="noindent1"><span class="drop">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<div class="box">
<p class="noindent-b">Some Text</p>
</div>
</break>
<break name="Chapter04">
<p class="ch-title"><a id="page_43">Some Text</p>
<p class="h1">Some Text</p>
<p class="h2">Some Text</p>
<div class="box">
<p class="noindent-b">Some Text</p>
</div>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="h3">Some Text</p>
<p class="h3">Some Text</p>
<div class="box">
<p class="noindent-b">Some Text</p>
</div>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="h3">Some Text</p>
<p class="noindent">Some Text</p>
<p class="h3">Some Text</p>
<div class="box">
<p class="noindent-b">Some Text</p>
</div>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="para">Some Text</p>
<p class="h5">Some Text</p>
</break>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, in this XML, I want to add an extra attribute id to all `ch-title`, `h1`, `h2` and so on and then save the file as a new `XML` file.

In my current approach, what I am doing works but if it finds a `<div class>` instead of `<p class>`, it skips everything. There can be n level of elements for `<p class>`.

I works and it puts the attributes where needed.

Is there a way to get what I want using linq?

This is what I have done:

```
int titleCount = 1;
int chTitle = 1;
int bmTitle = 1;
int fmTitle = 1;
int ptTitle = 1;
int appTitle = 1;
int infoTitle = 1;
foreach (var chapter in breakslist)
{
    string chapterBreak = chapter.Attribute("name").Value;
    XElement chapterParent = new XElement(tempNamespace + "break", new XAttribute("name", chapterBreak));
    xtempdoc.Root.Element(tempNamespace + "body").Add(chapterParent);
    int h1 = 1;
    int h2 = 1;
    int h3 = 1;
    int h4 = 1;
    int h5 = 1;
    int h6 = 1;
    var chapterParagraphs = chapter.Elements().ToList();
    foreach (var chapterElement in chapterParagraphs)
    {
        if (chapterElement.Name.LocalName == "p")
        {
            if (chapterElement.HasAttributes)
            {
                XAttribute firstAttributeValue = chapterElement.FirstAttribute;
                if (chapterElement.Attribute("id") != null)
                {
                    if (chapterElement.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("h1") || chapterElement.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("h2")
                     || chapterElement.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("h3") || chapterElement.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("h4")
                     || chapterElement.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("h5") || chapterElement.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("h6"))
                    {
                        chapterElement.Attribute("id").Remove();
                    }
                }
                if (firstAttributeValue.Name.LocalName == "class")
                {
                    string classAttributeValue = firstAttributeValue.Value;
                    if (classAttributeValue.Contains("-title"))
                    {
                        classAttributeValue = classAttributeValue.Substring(0, classAttributeValue.IndexOf("-"));
                        if (classAttributeValue == "ch")
                        {
                            var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                            attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", classAttributeValue + chTitle));
                            chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                            chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                            chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                            titleCount = chTitle;
                            chTitle++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (classAttributeValue == "fm")
                        {
                            var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                            attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", classAttributeValue + fmTitle));
                            chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                            chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                            chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                            titleCount = fmTitle;
                            fmTitle++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (classAttributeValue == "bm")
                        {
                            var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                            attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", classAttributeValue + bmTitle));
                            chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                            chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                            chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                            titleCount = bmTitle;
                            bmTitle++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (classAttributeValue == "pt")
                        {
                            var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                            attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", classAttributeValue + ptTitle));
                            chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                            chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                            chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                            titleCount = ptTitle;
                            ptTitle++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (classAttributeValue == "app")
                        {
                            var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                            attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", classAttributeValue + appTitle));
                            chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                            chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                            chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                            titleCount = appTitle;
                            appTitle++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (classAttributeValue == "info")
                        {
                            var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                            attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", classAttributeValue + infoTitle));
                            chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                            chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                            chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                            titleCount = infoTitle;
                            infoTitle++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (classAttributeValue.StartsWith("h1"))
                    {
                        var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                        attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", "h1" + "_" + titleCount + "-" + h1));
                        chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                        chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                        chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                        h1++;
                    }
                    else if (classAttributeValue.StartsWith("h2"))
                    {
                        var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                        attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", "h2" + "_" + titleCount + "-" + h2));
                        chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                        chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                        chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                        h2++;
                    }
                    else if (classAttributeValue.StartsWith("h3"))
                    {
                        var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                        attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", "h3" + "_" + titleCount + "-" + h3));
                        chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                        chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                        chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                        h3++;
                    }
                    else if (classAttributeValue.StartsWith("h4"))
                    {
                        var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                        attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", "h4" + "_" + titleCount + "-" + h4));
                        chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                        chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                        chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                        h4++;
                    }
                    else if (classAttributeValue.StartsWith("h5"))
                    {
                        var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                        attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", "h5" + "_" + titleCount + "-" + h5));
                        chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                        chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                        chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                        h5++;
                    }
                    else if (classAttributeValue.StartsWith("h6"))
                    {
                        var attributes = chapterElement.Attributes().ToList();
                        attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("id", "h6" + "_" + titleCount + "-" + h6));
                        chapterElement.Attributes().Remove();
                        chapterElement.Add(attributes);
                        chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                        h6++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chapterParent.Add(chapterElement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with my code from previous posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887897/how-do-i-create-child-xelement-based-on-values-in-c.  Can you post sample of xml output that you want to make things simpler.  You code is more complicated than it should be.  Again the xml is not meeting schema